# How to write values to excel using python3?

Tags: excel, python-3.x

How to write values to excel using python3?

```
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re

input_file = "No. ; HP 0136510545","good"

for line in input_file:
if "HP" in line:
    s= line  
    hp = re.findall('\d+', s)
    print(hp)


data = [["hp"],[hp]]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Input.xlsx')
workbook.close()

wb = load_workbook("Input.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

for row_data in data:
    ws.append(row_data)

 wb.save("excel_file.xlsx") 


Expected Result:
0136510545

Got Result:
['0136510545']
```

I got error as cannot convert to excel i dono why but when  i try to write as sheet1.write(0,0,hp) it will work whats wrong in my code? pls help me

Comment: Btw, instead of creating the file with XlsxWriter and then reopening it with OpenPyXL you could just create it with OpenPyXL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change as follows:
`data = [["hp"],hp]`

Comment: @jmcnamara, agreed.  no need to import two libraries.  OpenPyXL should be able to take care of everything in this case